# Operation is Insecure - watermark.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, watermark

I am using watermark.js for image protection on a WordPress site.

While testing, I found a error in **img.src = gcanvas.toDataURL();**. I've tried to find where to set this value but I keep failing so far.

This is the code I'm using - can anyone see what's going wrong?

**Code**

```
var load = false;
    window.onload = function(){
        if(!load) {
            wmark.init({
                /* config goes here */
                "position": "top-center", // default "bottom-right"
                "opacity": 50, // default 50
                "className": "watermark", // default "watermark"
                                    "path": "<?php echo WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/'. dirname(plugin_basename( __FILE__ ));?>/images/watermark.png", // plugindir
            });


            load = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: why there is a check for `load` as `window.onload` happens just once so every time it is `false` when window loaded the load sets to `true`. so in short i think it will never get in the condition.

Comment: @Jai now i am clear what u say . but problem is came on path is unsecure.

Comment: @Jai SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
 

img.src = gcanvas.toDataURL();

Answer (score 0):

Finally I research myself and implemented as working solution finally here it is best instead of dom just remove dom and try it should did a trick

```
<script  type="text/javascript">

               jQuery('img').each(function($) {
                  jQuery(this).attr('class','watermark'); 

               });
                        wmark.init({
                    /* config goes here */
                    "position": "top-center", // default "bottom-right"
                    "opacity": 50, // default 50
                    "className": "watermark", // default "watermark"
                    "path": "watermark.png", // plugindir
                });

            </script>
```